# Is there a better way to define model from server data?

Tags: ember.js

The following code works and does everything i need, but it is not very clean. It would be awesome if someone could point out a better way to accomplish my task. I have commented the code to explain why I think it could be better.

This code defines a model for my BuildingRoute and updates it with data from the server.

```
App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  buildingData : {      // Can't I just create the object once my data comes,
    name: '',           // is it necessary to initialize this object?
    addr1: '',
    addr2: ''
  },

  model: function() {
    this.getNodeInfo();     // should I be calling the function to access the server here?
    return this.buildingData;
  },

  getNodeInfo: function(){
    var _this = this;
    var req = {
      callback: nodeDataCB,
      something: {
        method: 'getNode',
        uid: 'getNodeData',
        nodeId: gVars.node
      }
    }
    Server.getData(req);

    function nodeDataCB(data){
      console.log($.parseXML(data));
      var attributes = $(data).find('attributes');
      var addr1 = attributes.find('attr[n="disAddress1"]').html();
      var addr2 = attributes.find('attr[n="disAddress2"]').html();
      var name = $(data).find('name').text();
      Ember.set(_this.buildingData, 'name', name);     // must I set the value for each
      Ember.set(_this.buildingData, 'addr1', addr1);   // specifically, can't i just set
      Ember.set(_this.buildingData, 'addr2', addr2);   // the whole object at once?
    }
  }
});
```

Should I be using Ember-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use promises. You can process the data returned by the server, then pass the final data to **resolve()**.

```
App.BuildingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
           Server.getData({
               something: {
                  method: 'getNode',
                  uid: 'getNodeData',
                  nodeId: gVars.node
               },

               callback: function(data) {
                   // your nodeDataCB here.
                   resolve(data);
               });
       });
   }
});
```